# How to convert sql_variant so it can be considered deterministic

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, deterministic, non-deterministic, sql-variant

I am trying to create a persisted computed column in a `SYSTEM_VERSIONING` table `dbo.Users` as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users 
    ADD SessionId AS usr.GetSession() PERSISTED 
        CONSTRAINT FK_dboUsers_IdSession 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Sessions(IdSession)
```

Where `usr.GetSession()` is just retrieving the value stored as `BIGINT` in `SESSION_CONTEXT('IdSession')` and converting it to again to `BIGINT`.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION usr.GetSession()
RETURNS BIGINT WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(BIGINT, SESSION_CONTEXT(N'IdSession'))
END
```

But getting the following error:

> Computed column 'SessionId' in table 'Users' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

It is obviously because:

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('usr.GetSession'), 'IsDeterministic') AS IsDeterministic;
```

Is returning **0**

A little bit of searching found this about [Deterministic and nondeterministic functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)

> CONVERT
> Deterministic unless one of these conditions exists:
>
> - Source type is sql_variant.
> - Target type is sql_variant and its source type is nondeterministic.

So, I am understanding that there is no way to make my computed column persisted with a user defined scalar function as `sql_variant` cannot be handled as deterministic value.

Or there can be some walk around to solve my problem? Or some other solution? Any idea?

Comment: No, there is no work around to make the conversion of a `sql_variant` to a different data type deterministic.

Comment: Even if there was, it would also depend on the function, and the function *cannot* be deterministic because it depends on the `SESSION_CONTEXT`. Honestly this feels like an XY problem: why do you want to persist something which depends on the session that's connected, and what do you expect to happen if another session connects?

Comment: I want to persist it to create a Foreign Key to the table of sessions dbo.sessions(IdSession). In order to indentify "IdSession" who modifies or deletes a row and store it in the history table of dbo.usersHistory, this way I ensure that Session who modifies or deletes a row is identified and cannot be corrupted by deleting the session in the future.

Comment: Sounds like you need it as a *default*, not as a computed column. It makes no sense to use it as a computed column, it would recalculate every time you *select* it, not just modify it.

Comment: 9 out of 10 times, when people think a persisted computed column is going to do what they want, they are wrong. This is because, despite what the name might seem to imply, `PERSISTED` does *not* mean "set once on creation". The value of a computed column is always based on the *current* state of the row, persisted or not. `PERSISTED` just removes the need for computing the value on the fly every time, and is necessary only if the result involves floating-point calculations -- at other times it's just a performance optimization/tradeoff (I/O for CPU) and does not offer different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is no workaround.** You cannot do anything with `sql_variant` unless you convert it (even implicitly), and as you mention, that is not deterministic.

---

Be that as it may, it seems you are going down the wrong road anyway.

**A computed column is the wrong thing here**, as in this case it would change every time it was read, whereas it seems you want it changed every time the row is inserted.

Instead you need a `DEFAULT`

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users 
    ADD SessionId bigint DEFAULT (usr.GetSession())
```

Comment: Thank for your answer @Charlieface , but this will not work for my purpose.
I do not really care about dbo.Users(SessionId) but more about dbo.UsersHistory(SessionId), which was automatically generated using option of system_versioning, where SessionId will be calculated every time the table is being UPDATED or DELATED and saved in dbo.UsersHistory, this way I will have a track on what changes the table suffer and WHO made it.

Comment: You can't have different columns on one as opposed to the other, the history table must match exactly. I still think you should create a `DEFAULT` rather than a computed column, otherwise it will change every time you select

Comment: No, there are not going to have different columns. Columns are identical. The thing is with computed column, history table saves the IdSession of WHO was updating/deleting. I already implemented Default constraint you are suggesting in another column called "CreatedBy" as constraint will only work for inserting new records.
See link below for better understanding:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602579/sql-server-2016-temporal-table-how-to-identify-the-user

The main difference is that he is using SUSER_SNAME() but I will like to use self table of session dbo.session(Id)