.NET SQL connection with SQL Server account and user identity
I have an ASP.NET app which connects to SQL Server using a SQL Server account. For auditing purposes, we use temporal tables which requires us to manually pass in the users doing the updates (AD accounts).
Is there any way to pass the users identity through to the SQL connection so we can setup triggers and avoid having to manually update the user with every update?

Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602579/sql-server-2016-temporal-table-how-to-identify-the-user

Have a look at SESSION_CONTEXT. It allows you to set sessions variables or pass additional information into a database session.
